# Error: socket hang up with executeAsync when running the test from the same server

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, nightwatch.js, zalenium

When running a selenium test with [nighwatch](https://nightwatchjs.org/) and [zalenium](https://opensource.zalando.com/zalenium/) that is deployed on a jenkins server, if the tests are executed from a remote system there is no issue but if the test is executed from the same jenkins server it will fail during [executeAsync](https://nightwatchjs.org/api/executeAsync.html#apimethod-page) with:

```
POST  /wd/hub/session/63a916e0c8ce50877bd38d8cf75a220f/execute_async - ECONNRESET
Error: socket hang up
```

I know this is a generic selenium error message that manifests in different occasions but would be awesome to know how to debug the problem.

the line of code that is failing

```
this.api.executeAsync()
```

this is how zalenium is started

`docker run -d -e NEW_SESSION_WAIT_TIMEOUT=9600 -e SEL_BROWSER_TIMEOUT_SECS=7800 -ti --name zalenium -p 4444:4444 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --privileged dosel/zalenium start --maxTestSessions 20 --seleniumImageName elgalu/selenium --videoRecordingEnabled false --keepOnlyFailedTests true --maxDockerSeleniumContainers 3`

From nightwatch side, the test is running normally and it just receives a `500` zalenium, on the other side I can't access selenium logs due to an issue with zalenium...

Comment: What line of code in JavaScript is throwing this exception? Can you post the code that initializes the web driver?

Comment: Please add this to your question, not as a comment.

Comment: description updated

Answer (score 0):

No suprise here, was just getting the wrong branch...